# Get Default Value Description in Crystal

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to get the default value description from a Crystal Reports parameter.  This is the code that I am using.  To test the value I am using a message box.  Here is my code.  The message box shows up empty.

```
foreach (ParameterField param in clsCrystal.cryRtp.ParameterFields)
{
    if (param.Name.Equals("ShowUp"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show( param.DefaultValues[0].Description.ToString());
    }
}
```

Edit:
I figured out how to get the values of the default values for a parameter field but the description is still evading me.  Here is the working code to get the value of the default values.

```
foreach (ParameterField param in clsCrystal.cryRtp.ParameterFields)
{
    if (param.Name.Equals("ShowUp"))
    {
        foreach (ParameterDiscreteValue Dvalue in param.DefaultValues)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the value is " + Dvalue.Value.ToString() + " and the description... " + Dvalue.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the **ParameterFields** is not as robust as **DataDefinition.ParameterFields**  I found the answer at this link.  http://scn.sap.com/thread/889809  Seems like *ParameterFields* is designed to make it easier to add values to parameters, while *DataDefinition.ParameterFields* are the real objects to play with if you actually want to look around at stuff.

```
foreach (ParameterFieldDefinition param in clsCrystal.cryRtp.DataDefinition.ParameterFields)
{
    if (param.Name.Equals("ShowUp"))
    {
        foreach (ParameterValue parameterValue in param.DefaultValues)
        {
            if (!parameterValue.IsRange)
            {
                ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = (ParameterDiscreteValue)parameterValue;
                MessageBox.Show(parameterDiscreteValue.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The incredibly confusing thing about the code and the documentation was that I could actually set and read the Default Descriptions in my code.  I just couldn't read them when they were set from the Crystal Reports Designer.